# Powershell help updating Active Directory attributes

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ADUser -Filter 'l -like "Atlanta"' -SearchBase 'OU=atl,DC=ego,DC=ga,DC=com' -Properties DisplayName | % {Set-ADUser $_ @{GMLocation='ATL'} }
```

I am trying to update the `GMLocation` of all users that have a location of Atlanta with the code above. Can someone help me figure out why it does not work?

Comment: `GMLocation` is a custom attribute on your Domain?

Comment: yes GMLocation is custom to our domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set-ADUser` expects you to use `-Replace <hashtable>` or `-Add <hashtable>`:

```sh
Get-ADUser -Filter "l -like 'Atlanta'" -SearchBase 'OU=atl,DC=ego,DC=ga,DC=com' |
Set-ADUser -Replace @{ GMLocation = 'ATL' }
```

You're also using `-Filter "l -like 'Atlanta'"` but no wildcards for `-like`, if you're looking for an exact match of `Atlanta` then use `-eq` for equality: **`-Filter "l -eq 'Atlanta'"`**. If instead, you're looking for partial match you should use **`-like` but add wildcards (`*`)**: **`-Filter "l -like '*Atlanta*'"`**.

If you want to add error handling to your code, you can use a `try { }` `catch { }` statement:

```sh
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

$param = @{
    Properties = 'GMLocation'
    SearchBase = 'OU=atl,DC=ego,DC=ga,DC=com'
    Filter = "l -like 'Atlanta'"
}
Get-ADUser @param | ForEach-Object {
    $adusrSplat = @{ Identity = $_ }
    if($_.GMLocation) {
        # If the user already have this Attribute Set
        # Replace it
        $adusrSplat['Replace'] = @{ GMLocation = 'ATL' }
    }
    else {
        # Else, Add this new Attribute for the User
        $adusrSplat['Add'] = @{ GMLocation = 'ATL' }
    }

    try {
        Set-ADUser @adusrSplat
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1819884 my pleasure, happy to help